# Copy lookup value from one list to another with SPD workflow

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

I have two lists and a workflow that copies items from list A, if they get approved, to list B.

Problem is that a field in list A uses a lookup list, if I select Dog in the Field Animal and save the item it displays Dog in list A. However, when the item is copied over to list B it displays the lookup ID in stead, so instead of dog it says 5 or whatever, how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

when you configure your lookup column for list B , check that you are referring to Lookup ID instead of any other value.

Answer (score 0):

Check [SPD Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) ... this can be used to copy list items... in SharePoint Designer Workflow... It has various custom actions for the workflow...